# Is it possible to discard all changes made to a volume after use?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my source repo I have a docker-compose file for running the code, and another docker-compose for running automated tests. Basically, these mount the src dir as a `volume` and then run the actual service or pytest, respectively, as a `command`.

Some of the tests run processes that create/remove files in the code tree (there's some templating stuff for creating files that will be consumed by another service, which has to be run to be validated). This is an issue because the directory I'm mounting into the test container is also my dev environment, and I don't want my tests to change that.

So what I really want is the ability to mount a volume in such a way that docker uses copy-on-write when the container makes changes to it, and discards those changes when the container shuts down.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why not store it in the container instead of volume. Because when you stop a container it will delete the files anyway.

Comment: Do you mean with a COPY statement? That would require a `--build` with each invocation, right? I could do that, but it would make developing tests painfully slow, and part of my goal here is to use docker to make local test execution as painless as possible.

Comment: The two way I can think of at the top of my mind: 1 Change your tests to output to a new directory and mount that a separate volume (or not mount it at all if you do not care for the results to persist. 2 Create a bash script that copies your directory, calls docker-compose and finally restores the original directory. Then you just run that script for running your tests.